# Sorting Data in a grid using TFDTable

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a `TFDTable` the is connected to a `TGrid` using `LiveBindings` and the data displays sorted by the indexes in the table itself. I want to be able to change the sort order by clicking on the header of the grid. Here is what I have done so far:

```
void __fastcall TmainFrm::Grid7HeaderClick(TColumn *Column)
{
    if(IBS_EntityTable->IndexName == Column->Header)
        return; // if it is being sorted by the same column, don't do anything
    try
    {
        TFDIndex* pIndex;

        IBS_EntityTable->Indexes->BeginUpdate();
        IBS_EntityTable->Indexes->Clear();
        pIndex = IBS_EntityTable->Indexes->Add();
        pIndex->Name = Column->Header;
        pIndex->Fields = Column->Header;
        pIndex->Active = true;
        IBS_EntityTable->IndexName = pIndex->Name;
    }
    __finally
    {
      IBS_EntityTable->Indexes->EndUpdate();
      IBS_EntityTable->Refresh();
    }
}
```

but the sort order does not change. In fact the only data that does change is the selected row. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you
Sam

Comment: Did you try to set `IBS_EntityTable->IndexFieldNames` instead of creating a new index? Does `Column->Header` contain the column name or its caption?

Comment: @serge I tried it after you suggested it. It does exactly the same thing.

Comment: What database do you use? Can you check SQL sent to server when changing order?

Comment: @serge I'm using Firebird for the moment, but the goal is to be able to change the database type on the fly. I could not wait, so I replaced the `TFDTable` with `TFDQuery` and took care of the problem by changing the SQL that gets executed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you may also take a look on my [FBProfiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fbprofiler/) which can trace and show what TFDTable do with DBMS.